# MySql Ignore in a Case

Tags: mysql, insert, case

```
Update acc
SET acc.lat = CASE
   WHEN acc.lat <> '' THEN INSERT (acc.lat,3,0,'°')
   WHEN acc.lat = '' THEN acc.lat = ''
   WHEN acc.lat LIKE '°' THEN (do nothing)
```

Everything works except I can't get it to ignore the `°` So every time it runs it adds another `°`

Comment: it's because of the first `when`, if the value is not equal to an empty string (which includes your weird character), then you have it set to insert a(nother) weird character...

Comment: so... do something like.... `WHEN acc.lat LIKE '%°%' or acc.lat = '' then acc.lat else insert(acc.lat,3,0,'°')`

Comment: gloomy.penguin THANK you, I've been racking my brain, that worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For your last clause don't you want it to be

```
WHEN acc.lat LIKE '%°' THEN (do nothing)
```

So it matches any string that ends in a `°`?

Comment: I do want it to ignore the '°' but no matter what I have tried so far it always adds another ° even if there is already one there.

Comment: Is it like @gloomy.penguin said, that once you set anything in `att.lat` it is not equal so the `<>` is always true and the first clause gets executed over and over?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the "ignore" in the `case` by referring to the original value:

```
Update acc
    SET acc.lat = (CASE WHEN acc.lat <> '' THEN INSERT(acc.lat, 3, 0, '°')
                        WHEN acc.lat = '' THEN ''
                        WHEN acc.lat LIKE '°' THEN acc.lat
                   END);
```

This will set unmatched values to `NULL`.  You probably intend this:

```
update acc
    then lat = concat(lat, '°')
    where lat not like '%°' and lat <> '';
```

This will put the symbol at the end of latitudes that have a value.